# Why does saving an iteratively constructed value to a predefined Eigen vector have a high computational cost?

Tags: c++, eigen3

While profiling my code, I found some strange behavior with the following code fragment:

```
Eigen::MatrixXcd bfVec(idxt.rows(),1);
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i = 0; i < idxt.rows(); i++) {
            
            bfVec(i) = calcPoint(idxt,SIG,ic,i);
        }
```

I found the execution time of my whole program (which includes the above fragment) to be ~0.045 seconds. However, if I don't store the output of calcPoint(...) in bfVec:

```
Eigen::MatrixXcd bfVec(idxt.rows(),1);
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i = 0; i < idxt.rows(); i++) {
            
            calcPoint(idxt,SIG,ic,i);
        }
```

the execution time of my whole program reduces dramatically to ~0.0217 seconds.

This is the code for calcPoint:

```
template <typename DerivedA, typename DerivedB> 
    std::complex<double> calcPoint(const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedA>& idxt, const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedB>& SIG,const std::complex<double>& ic, const int& i) {
        std::complex<double> bfVal;
        for (int j = 0; j < idxt.cols(); j++) {
            if(idxt(i,j) >= 0) {
                double vidxt = idxt(i,j) - static_cast<double>(static_cast<int>(idxt(i,j)*0.25))*4 - 2;
                int vIDX = static_cast<int>(idxt(i,j));
                double interp1 = (vIDX + 1 - idxt(i,j));
                double interp2 = (idxt(i,j) - vIDX);
                bfVal += (SIG(vIDX,j)*interp1 + SIG(vIDX+1,j)*interp2)*calcRot(vidxt,ic);
            }
        }
        return bfVal;
    }
```

I suspect this has something to do with how the compiler (GCC) is implementing Return Value Optimization, but I'm not sure. Where exactly is the cost of 0.02 seconds coming from?

Clarification:

The timings were an average of several hundred runs of this code. This code snippet is representative of a similar code that will have to run on much larger datasets, so I'm less interested in the exact timing and more interested in the relative timing. In otherwords, why does it take almost 50% of the runtime to just save a single complex value to memory?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a dramatic change from `0.045` to `0.027`! By the way, these are small timings and without good statistics it's difficult to criticize on performance.

Comment: Also, I think is not so clear which test cases you compare. Could you please clarify this better?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by alternative test cases.

Comment: I mean to clarify which two different codes you compare.  (I didn't use the work alternative)

Comment: If your compiler can prove that the `calcPoint()` function has no side effect, and you're discarding the return value unused, the compiler may just not emit *any* code for your function, and remove the loop calling it too.

Comment: Good point. Is there some way I can force the compiler to not omit this specific bit of code?

Comment: I think some benchmarking frameworks have macros to tell the compiler to not optimize away a computation. They probably use some compiler-specific pragmas (like disabling optimizations at a specific point in the code). I'd consider it bad form, and instead make sure the result is actually used. You could for example sum the results of the function calls in the loop and return the sum (openmp has reductions for `+`, so it should still parallelize).

Comment: Eigen's index operator does range checks unless you compile with ```-DNDEBUG```. To check whether this might be the issue, try ```bfVec.data()[i] = calcPoint(...)``` to access the raw array instead.